# INTNX Function is One Day Off

Tags: sas

I am using the INTNX function to calculate month intervals. I'm finding that the results are frequently one day off from what I would expect... For example, look at this code:

```
data test;
    olddate='20140531';
    oldsasdate=input(olddate,yymmdd8.);
    newsasdate=intnx('month',oldsasdate,-17);
    newdate=put(newsasdate,yymmdd8.);
run;
```

In this code, I try to find the date 17 months before 05/31/2014. I would expect the function to return 11/30/2012, but it instead returns 12/1/2012. Any idea what's going on here? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Note, even if same aligned, it shouldn't return 11/30, but rather 12/31, based on your code (17 months before May 31 is Dec 31: May is month 5, so 5 months back gives december, and then 12 more for december before that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for `intnx` is to align with the start of the month.  It basically tracks interval boundaries, so each time it goes from MM/01/YY to MM/30/YY it ticks one interval crossed.

So,

```
data _null_;
 x  = intnx('month','31MAY2014'd, -1);
 put x= date9.;
run;
```

Returns '01APR14'd, not '30APR14'd.

You can change it to 'same' alignment with the optional 4th parameter (SAS 9.2+ I believe).

```
data _null_;
 x  = intnx('month','31MAY2014'd, -1,'s');
 put x= date9.;
run;
```